# I have been trying to use Puppeteer to login into a website

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have being trying to use Puppeteer to login into [this website](https://www.biuportal.net/LogIn.aspx) and then find a div  but it has been given me strange error:

```
puppeteer.launch({
  headless:false
}).then(async browser => {
  console.log("jdwjdjwd")
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.biuportal.net/LogIn.aspx#', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000})
  await page.click('a#modalCloseBtn');
  await page.type('#txtUserName', "bas/csc/170387");
  await page.type("#txtPassword", "password1");
  await page.click("#btnLogin")
  await page.waitForSelector("div#NameHolder")
 const x =   await page.$eval("div#NameHolder", el=>el.innerHTML)
 console.log(x)
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a waitforNavigation before the waitForSelector.

```
await page.waitForNavigation;
//maybe try page._frameManager._mainFrame.waitForNavigation()

await page.waitForSelector("body > section > div:nth-child(3) > ul", {
   timeout: 30000
});

const StoreList_ul = await page.$$("body > section > div:nth-child(3) > ul");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please never put sensitive data on a public website!
2. You're waiting for the wrong selector. `div#NameHolder` must be `div.NameHolder`

```js
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.biuportal.net/LogIn.aspx#', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000})
  await page.click('a#modalCloseBtn');
  await page.type('#txtUserName', "bas/csc/170387");
  await page.type("#txtPassword", "password1");
  await page.click("#btnLogin")
  await page.waitForSelector("div.NameHolder")
  const x = await page.$eval("div.NameHolder", el=>el.innerHTML)
  console.log(x)
```